# Representation of a group on a vector space induces a representation on another representation space?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Caveat: this is a very basic question.

Suppose you have a representation of a group $G$ on a vector space $V$, let's say to be concrete $\mathbb{R}^n$. How is this representation related to the one that is induced on a vector space $W$ constructed out of $V$? E.g. the space of scalar function on $V$; $\lbrace \phi \mid \phi: x \in V \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \rbrace$?

Comment: That obviously depends on how you induce the representation.

Comment: In what what does a representation over $V$ *induce* a representation over $W$?  Is $W$ a subspace of $V$, perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

The term *induced* has a special meaning in   representation  theory. I guess you mean some representation *associated* in some way to the given representation.  For a given representation $\rho\colon G\to \mathrm{Aut\,} (V)$, consider an individual automorphisms $\rho(g)\colon V\to V$ for all $g\in G$.

Now for a $\phi\colon V\to \mathbf{R}$ (a linear map, an element of dual $V^*$) consider the composition $\phi\circ \rho(g^{-1})$. This is another linear map $ V\to \mathbf{R}$. Denote this by $\tilde \rho (g)$. It is easy to check that $\tilde\rho$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to Aut$(\,V^*)$.  This is called the dual representation.

Answer (score 2):

In general, that would depend on how you construct $W$ out of $V.$ In your example the natural representation to look at would consist of the linear transformations of the (infinite dimensional) $W$ defined by

$$(gf)(v):=f(g^{-1}v).$$

If you look at the *linear* scalar functions on $V$ then a similar construction gives you the dual representation of the original. Its matrices with respect to the dual basis are the transposes of the original matrices.

Comment: You want $gf(v) = f(g^{-1}v)$ to make it a left action.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks; I will adapt the answer.